# Suppose that the function $f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $f(x) \ge 2$ if $0 \le x < 1$. Show that $f(1) \ge 2$.

Tags: real-analysis

How do we do this? Does it involve the fact that we know $f$ is continuous, and therefore the limit approaching the endpoint $1$ should be the same coming from both sides?

Comment: There is only one side here, nothing larger than $1$ exists in the domain.

Comment: If $f(1) < 2$, then ...

Comment: DId you mean $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2):

If $f(1)<2$ then $\epsilon=2-f(1)$ is positive. Since $f$ is continuous and $f(0)\ge 2$, then there exists some $c\in[0,1)$ such that $f(c)=2-\frac\epsilon2$. Contradiction.

Comment: Why do we know that about f(c)? What is the theorem?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative topological solution:

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$ for all $A \subset [0,1]$

Applying this to $[0,1)$:

$f([0,1]) \subset \overline{f([0,1))} \subset \overline{[2,\infty)} = [2,\infty)$